# Can a secret message be securely transmitted within a MAC tag?

Tags: encryption, hash, mac, authenticated-encryption, skein

A sender wants to transmit an *ultra secret* code $M$ which could be either 'go', 'stop' or 'wait'. This could be any selection of code words really and adopted for any use such as transmitting short commands or short status messages. The code list could also be specific or relevant to a current mission/objective. A limited number of code words will make things a lot faster for the recipient however. I will try explain:

- Both sender and recipient know the valid code list $L$ and share a random 256 bit key $K$ beforehand. This exchange is out of scope.
- Let $H$ be a secure hash function with an output of 256 bits which also claims to be a secure MAC in the format of $H$($K$ | $M$). Skein and possibly a few others fit this criteria.
- Sender generates a random 256 bit nonce $N$ per transmission.
- Sender generates a MAC tag $T$ by calculating $H$($K$ | $N$ | $M$);
- Sender sends $N$ | $T$ in the clear to the recipient.

The recipient tries each message in the code list with the nonce and key to try get a match with the sent MAC tag and thus decipher the message:

```
function(K, L, N, T) {
   foreach M in L {
      if (T equals H(K | N | M)) {
         return M
      }
   }
   return invalid
}
```

You will note there is no separate MAC tag sent to authenticate the nonce and MAC tag sent in the clear. Because there are only 3 valid codes, there are only 3 possible MACs considered valid by the recipient. This increases the attacker's chance of a creating a forgery to 2^256 / 3 = 2^254 but this is still comfortably secure. You could in fact have 1000 code words and the security would still be adequate at 2^246. However shorter code lists would be better to prevent a DOS type attack when an attacker sends fake transmissions causing excess MAC validation work for the receiver. For longer code lists, perhaps a separate MAC of the $N$ and $T$ would fix that.

From what I can ascertain, only the recipient should know the true message. An attacker can if they do a brute force of the key space (2^256 difficulty) or break the hash function. There is practically no chance of the receiver interpreting the transmitted code incorrectly because the odds of a valid code word producing the same MAC tag is extremely unlikely due to the collision resistance of the hash function.

**Can a secret message be securely transmitted, authenticated and read like this?**

Comment: If the code word count is limited enough there are more simple options, such as using AES_CTR and the block counter being the codeword. The sent message would be 28 bytes, you have $2^{32}$ options for code words, and you only need to decrypt once (no more DOS)

Comment: @Richie Frame, but is AES_CTR considered a secure MAC? Otherwise you would need more bytes for a MAC tag too.

Comment: it is a secure block cipher, CTR in this case is the same as N | AES_ECB(N | M), and even if the attacker knows N, he does not know the key to the block cipher. If you want to encode the secret inside the MAC of a **different message**, then this can also be used, and you encrypt the actual MAC with AES_CTR under the super secret key

Comment: @Richie, sounds more complicated. The advantage with my scheme is you could encode messages of variable length and it produces a fixed output ciphertext and MAC in one. I don't think AES can do that, can it?

Comment: Your scheme does not produce ciphertext, mine does not produce a MAC. And yes, you can encode larger messages, but as you said your messages will probably be less than 8-bits in size

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this proposal: the use of a [code book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codebook#Cryptography) and a scheme to send short confidential and authenticated messages utilising an existing shared symmetric key.

A code book can be used alone to provide a degree of confidentiality, or can be used to ascribe specific pre-agreed meanings to short messages, in combination with any scheme for sending those short messages. The rest of this answer focuses on the use of a MAC for sending such short messages.

Short answer: yes, this scheme preserves confidentiality and integrity of messages.

Pre-image resistance of the secure hash function ensures confidentiality of the message (in conjunction with an appropriately strong key).

The use of a nonce ensures that an eavesdropper can't tell whether a genuine message is the same as any previous messages.

The properties of a MAC prevent forgeries or manipulated messages being accepted.

Note that this system does not protect against replay attacks or message re-ordering attacks, i.e. it can't be used as a generic secure channel. Once an attacker has observed a message, they can replay the message and the recipient cannot differentiate between a replayed message and a fresh message. If the recipient were to record all valid nonce-message pairs they could detect replays, but not out-of-order messages.

This use of a MAC isn't a standard way to build a secure messaging system, so [shouldn't be used](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) for production systems. Practically, it has very large message expansion (256 bit ciphertext + 256 bit nonce per ~10 bit data transferred = ~500bit overhead per 10 bit message). An example of a standardised alternative is GCM, which is more size-efficient (96bit nonce + up to 128bit tag = up to 224bit fixed overhead per any length of message) as well as supporting very long messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was mainly just asking about the confidentiality and authentication as I was considering using it in a channel which is already protected against reordering or replaying attacks. Anyway one could easily send a sequence number with each message. Or check for repeated nonces, then use a timestamp as well to reject messages outside of a valid time window or that have been reordered.

Comment: `has massive message expansion (384 bit ciphertext incl nonce per ~10 bit message)` Well actually it's 512 bit ciphertext including the nonce. Point is, the message can be any length and it would produce the same length ciphertext. As long as the sender and receiver agree on the code book in advance, they can send entire sentences e.g. 'Attack these coordinates', followed by 'Latitude', '127', '134', '233', 'Longitude', '222', '321', '12', 'Time', '14', '45'. Or 'Wait until midnight' etc.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the length. The actual data sent is of very restricted size, which is what I am referring to by 'message'. How this message is interpreted is up to the system it exists in as you point out. I wouldn't recommend using this non-standard approach - I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I'm not really interested in your "recommendations". I asked a specific question about whether it was secure or not. It does appear to be secure regardless of whether or not it's considered "standard" or inefficient.

Comment: I notice you decided to use a 96 bit GCM tag to compare it. This *lowers* the security and is not secure against a quantum computer. Let's compare apples to apples for a minute. If you paired the AES CTR mode cipher with HMAC-SHA256 and a message of the same length, my scheme is actually *more* efficient in terms of ciphertext length. For an arbitrary length, let's say 200 bit message, my scheme would total 512 bits. That is a fixed length for any message size. For your CTR mode scheme you have 256 bit nonce + ciphertext + padding + 256 bit MAC. That would be 712 bits or more.

Comment: As for efficiency in encryption speed, my scheme with one invocation of the hash function produces the ciphertext and MAC. This beats the multiple invocations of AES in counter mode to encrypt the plaintext and then HMAC to authenticate as well.

Comment: The only slow part in comparison to AES CTR mode would be the decryption. However this can be sped up by breaking early from the loop when a message match is found. The decryption can also be done in parallel with *n* CPU cores by splitting up the code book then testing for each message on multiple CPU cores.

Comment: If communication participants can keep the code book as secret as the key, then use the numeric index of the code/message in the code book instead of the words i.e. `H(K | N | Mi)`, then the confidentiality of the messages is actually unbreakable. After an attacker has performed an impractical 2^256 operations to brute force the key, all that is revealed is a number which refers to the message. Without the code book, this number is meaningless.

Comment: If using the numeric index of the code book, an attacker does not know how many messages are in the code book. It could be from 1 - n. If an attacker is testing the possible 256 bit keys with various numeric counters from 1 - n, they may encounter a collision in the hash function due to the generic birthday attack in 2^128 time. This could mean there are multiple keys which appear to give valid encryptions and MACs. An attacker would not know which is the valid key or which is a chance collision, frustrating cryptanalysis significantly.

Comment: I think my scheme is more secure than you're giving it credit for and undeserving of the presumptuous "why we shouldn't roll our own" response. We're all here to learn and discuss.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the code book and MAC scheme separately. My answer doesn't say that this scheme is insecure - indeed it states just the opposite! The 'don't roll your own' axiom remains true though; I've clarified that it applies to production systems.

Comment: I agree with ushadm that GCM would not be a good idea if the tag size needs to be shortened.

Comment: I would accept this answer if the "shouldn't be used for production systems" comment is removed. If it were implemented properly, including additional protections for replay protections etc then it would be secure if it is implemented by a competent engineer. Also I don't see the point in recommending an alternative completely different solution (GCM), that's not what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I don't see why this scheme would not be secure. It uses a MAC over known data - protected against replay. If that data is received or calculated locally shouldn't matter.

But as you already showed yourself, you bring down the security of the tag with the amount of bits required to calculate the options. So in the end you could as well just CTR-encrypt the $m$ bits of the message $M$ and create a tag value $t$ that is $m$ bits shorter in size.

There is already have a nonce (which is unnecessarily large) and shared secret in the protocol, so there is nothing preventing the use of AES-CTR within the scheme. The only disadvantage of this scheme is that you may loose one bit of space (as you will require two bits to encode a value with 3 possibilities).